# Unable to save files into a partition subfolder in gen 2 using Databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I have a gen2 account with a container. Inside the container is a  folder, inside the folder are  8 partitioned subfolders. The storage account structure is as follows.

```
storage account/
  container/
    folder/
      8 sub folders/
```

I am using Databricks to transform my dataset. I have mounted the storage account onto databricks.(/mnt/container/folder/) I have used the code (display(dbutils.fs.mounts())) to check if the folder has been mounted, which it has.
i am trying to save the csv dataset as parquet into the partitioned sub folders,(one file per sub folder), however it's only saving the files inside the folder level and not into the sub folder level.
How would I save the files into the partitioned sub folders?

Comment: Please provide info on how you are trying to 'save' your csv dataset and the path you are trying to write to. provide the `<dataframe>.write.` command. 
Have you trying to write a partitioned table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if your mount is at the folder level your write function should look like this:

```
dfCsv.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('ColumnYouWantFromTheDataset').parquet('/mnt/container/folder/')
```

This will create sub folders based on the column from the dataset you want to use to do the partition.